# Closure and interior in subset topology

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-domain

Let $\tau $ be a topology on set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ with subset topology from $\mathbb{R}$ (with Euclidean topology).

Find clousure and interior sets:

$A= \lbrace \pi * (1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$, $B=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} : 1 < x \le \sqrt2 \rbrace$ , $C= \lbrace e+ \frac{1}{n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$.

I think that,

$cl(A)=(A  \cup \lbrace \pi e \rbrace ) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$,

$int(A)= \emptyset$,

$cl(B)=[1, \sqrt2 ] \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$,

$int(B)= \emptyset$,

$cl(C)=(C \cup \lbrace  e \rbrace ) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$,

$int(C)= \emptyset$.

Can you tell me, if I think right? 
If not, I will be grateful for any advice :)

Comment: One hint: $(1, \sqrt{2}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$ is open in the subspace topology, and it's a subset of $B$, so we must have $\operatorname{int}(B) \supseteq (1, \sqrt{2}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: They seem okay to me.  But it be more useful if you gave your *reasons* you think those are the answer and we could critique those.  In mathematics we very rarely actually *care* about answers; we only care about reasons.

Comment: By the way $[1,\sqrt 2]\cap \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q = \{x\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q| 1 < x\le \sqrt 2\} = B$.  So (assuming we are are correct) $cl(B)= B$.

Comment: Also $(C\cup \{e\})\subset \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ so (assuming we are correct) $cl(C) = C\cup \{e\}$ and we don't need to state "$\cap \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$".  .... However it is unknown whether $\pi\cdot e$ is irrational (!) so for $A$ we have $cl(A) = A\cup \{\pi e\}$ if $\pi e$ is irrational and $cl(A) = A$ if it isn't.  In either case $cl(A) = (A\cup\{\pi e\}\cap\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ and the  "$\cap \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$" *does* need to be stated.